# Three.js with typescript autocomplete

Tags: node.js, typescript, three.js

I have a Node.js project that uses Typescript and Three.js. To import modules, I use the commonjs syntax, which I configured via

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

in my `tsconfig.json`. I downloaded Three.js via NPM have a typescript file like this:

```
const THREE = require('three');
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

which compiles fine, but I do not get any autocomplete. I don't think this specific to the editor used, as both Visual Studio Code as well as Neovim with YouCompleteMe don't work. Both work if I use the ES6 module syntax:

```
import * as THREE from 'node_modules/three/src/Three';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

Here however I cannot get it to work without giving the actual path to the library (which is a problem later on when using webpack). What did I forget to configure to get autocomplete (or the ES6 syntax without explicitly defining the path, at this point I am fine with both solutions)?

### EDIT

As mentioned in the comments to accepted answer, I was not able to find my mistake, but found a working solution while trying to create a minimal working project. So I will post this here, in case it might help someone else. If you have the same problem, please still read the answer, as it is correct.

My source file (in `src/main.ts`):

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

`package.json` (with webpack to test if the library can be resolved there):

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.0.4",
    "three": "^0.105.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.5.1",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": { "*": ["types/*"] },
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/"
  ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    module: {
        rules : [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: [ 'ts-loader' ], exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of `three` is installed in your `package.json` file? Make sure it's `0.101` or later, since that's when TypeScript support began. I recommend you use the latest (105 as of this writing), since it gets updated definition files on each release.

Then, in your .ts files, you can import it with:

```
import * as THREE from "three";

// After importing, THREE is available for auto-complete.
var lala = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

**Edit:**

You might need to perform [path-mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in your `.tsconfig` file to force the compiler to find the correct module address. I've never had to do this, but the Typescript documentation suggests something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
    "paths": {
      "three": ["node_modules/three/src/Three"] // relative to "baseUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update r126

As of revision `r126`, Three.js has moved Typescript declaration files to a separate repository. If you're using `r126` or later, you'll have to run `npm install @types/three` as a second step. Make sure [you install the version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/three) of `@types/three` that targets your version of Three.js. For example:

```
"three": "0.129.0",
"@types/three": "^0.129.1",
```

Comment: I already use Three.js version 0.105.2, but the syntax suggested by you (ES6 with just 'three') does not work for me ("Cannot find module 'three'")

Comment: That's strange. I edited my answer to provide an alternative path-mapping method in case your compiler needs a little push to find the module. It depends on your folder hierarchy, but typically you'd have `.tsconfig` and `node_modules/` folder in the same location. You might run into problems if they're at different folder depths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At first, it did not work for me, so I tried to create a minimal project to post for you to reproduce the problem. In this minimal example, your first solution already works and I do not have to set the path to Three.js explicitly, even with the ES6 syntax. Apparently I had messed up my configuration somewhere. I will still post the (now working) minimal example, in case someone might need it.